# how to pass select subquery in where clause using laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my SQl query

```
select sum(stock.total_in_stock) as total_in_stock
    ,stock.name
    ,stock.inventory_id 
from (
    select i.store_id
        ,i.model_id
        ,i. total_in_stock
        ,i.id as inventory_id
        , m.* 
    from `inventory` as `i` 
    left join `model_store` as `ms` on `ms`.`store_id` = `i`.`store_id`
    left join `model` as `m` on `m`.`id` = `ms`.`model_id` 
    where `i`.`model_id` = m.id 
    and `m`.`status` = 1 
    and `ms`.`status` = 1 
    and `i`.`created_at` = (
        select si.created_at 
        from inventory AS si 
        where si.model_id = i.model_id 
        and si.store_id = i.store_id 
        and si.status=1 
        order by si.created_at desc limit 1
    )
) as stock 
group by stock.model_id
```

In laravel, it is written as this:

```
$results1 = DB::table('inventory as i')
                ->select(DB::raw( 'sum(stock.total_in_stock) as total_in_stock,stock.name,stock.inventory_id FROM ( SELECT i.store_id,i.model_id,i. total_in_stock,i.id as inventory_id, m.* '))                      
                ->leftJoin('model_store as ms','ms.store_id','=','i.store_id')
                ->leftJoin('model as m','m.id','=','ms.model_id')
                ->where('i.model_id','=', 'm.id')
                ->where('m.status','=', '1')
                ->where('ms.status','=', '1')
                ->where("i.created_at","=",function($query) {
                    $query->select(DB::raw("si.created_at FROM inventory AS si WHERE si.model_id = i.model_id AND si.store_id = i.store_id AND si.status=1 ORDER BY si.created_at DESC LIMIT 1)) as stock GROUP BY stock.model_id"));
                });
```

It gives me the following error:-

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: select sum(stock.total_in_stock) as total_in_stock,stock.name,stock.inventory_id FROM ( SELECT i.store_id,i.model_id,i. total_in_stock,i.id as inventory_id, m.* from `inventory` as `i` left join `model_store` as `ms` on `ms`.`store_id` = `i`.`store_id` left join `model` as `m` on `m`.`id` = `ms`.`model_id` where `i`.`model_id` = m.id and `m`.`status` = 1 and `ms`.`status` = 1 and `i`.`created_at` = (select si.created_at FROM inventory AS si WHERE si.model_id = i.model_id AND si.store_id = i.store_id AND si.status=1 ORDER BY si.created_at DESC LIMIT 1 )) as stock GROUP BY stock.model_id))
```

It takes 2 closing brackets at the end and gives the above error. Please help me writing the above SQL query in laravel.

Comment: You have a better chance at receiving an answer if you explain what the queries use should be, I for one am not going to sit here and reverse engineer this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question that's in the tile: the subquery where needs fix:

```
->where("i.created_at", function($query) {
    $query->from('inventory as si')
          ->selectRaw('max(si.created_at)')
          ->whereRaw('si.model_id = i.model_id AND ...');
});
```

However, in order to create a subquery in the `from` clause, you need to pass raw query, so your whole code requires a bit of `toSql()` and `setBindings(...)`, which is cumbersome.

So to get **the** answer to your problem, better describe the problem itself instead.